# Rails 3 + ActiveRecord - select with condition for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, select, model, associations

I have `Car` (table `cars`) method that `has_many` owners (table `owners`). How can I choose all cars, that has no owners (== in the table `owners` is no one row with respective car's ID)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it as per below in the model....

```
@cars_without_owners = Car.where("owner_id = ?", nil)
```

or to be safe....

```
@cars_without_owners = Car.where("owner_id = ? OR owner_id = ?", nil, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this, although it would be very slow if your tables have many records:

```
Car.where("not exists (select o.id from owners as o where o.car_id = cars.id)")
```